# Solving linear system subject to constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the following system of equations: $$ \begin{bmatrix} A_1 + \delta A_2 \\
A_3 \end{bmatrix} x =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ b \end{bmatrix}, $$
where $\delta$ is a scalar. Suppose that all the $A$'s have full row-rank and that the system is invertible, so that given $\delta$ the system can be solved for $x$ using standard linear solvers.
The complication arises, because $\delta$ is determined jointly with $x$ by the following scalar equation $$ (\delta c_1' + c_2')x = 1, $$
where $c_1'$ and $c_2'$ are row-vectors matching the length of $x$. I am trying to solve the joint system numerically for $x$ and $\delta$.

What would be a good approach to do so that scales well in the case where the $A$'s are large and sparse. For instance, is there any clever way of combining the scalar equation with the rest of the system and still use standard linear solvers?

---

The best two approaches I can think of seem both numerically intensive:

1. Solving the scalar equation for $\delta = (1-c_2'x) / (c'_1x)$ and substituting into the matrix equation yields a nonlinear system in $x$ that I don't know how to solve easily.
2. Alternatively, I was thinking of implementing a numerical search over $\delta$ where for a given guess for $\delta$ I solve for $x = x(\delta)$ from the first system, and then back out the implied $\delta$ from the scalar system. However, that requires repeatedly solving the linear system of equations, which would be very expensive in my case.

Comment: I'm not really following why you have it separated or labelled this way.  Why don't you append $c_1'$ to $A_2$ and append $c_2'$ to $A_1$  then you have $\begin{bmatrix} A_1' + \delta A_2'\\
A_3 \end{bmatrix} \mathbf x =  \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf 0\\ 1 \\ \mathbf b \end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Yes, you could, but I don't see yet how this would help in solving the system? Am I missing something obvious? @user8675309